# What happens with /etc/fstab when using an initramfs?

Tags: embedded, fstab, initramfs, syslinux, buildroot

I have a simple embedded setup as follows: x86 target, kernel and root file system built using buildroot. Syslinux is the bootloader configured to boot with an initramfs which points to a .cpio file generated from the buildroot generated root file system. My system boots and works as I am expecting, but I am confused as to what happens with the entries contained in /etc/fstab. I would like my system to be able to mount the /var directory as a partition on an attached compact flash device for various reasons (mainly because I want to be able to store and run an application on the compact flash and additionally store log data here). Is it possible to use an initramfs and yet mount /var on device outside of RAM? If that is the case, is /etc/fstab the correct place to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any directory path can have any (valid) volume mounted to it. Whether or not `/etc/fstab` is the correct place to put it depends on whether or not your embedded setup even uses it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an easy way for me to find out if /etc/fstab is being used by my setup? I am not an expert in linux unfortunately.

Comment: Nope. You'll need to investigate the startup scripts to see how they use `mount` to bring filesystems up.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I dare say the easy way to find out is to add something to `/etc/fstab` and see if it works.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ok I will try that. Thanks very much for your help.